# Laravel fullUrlWithoutQuery($keys) removes all parameters

Tags: php, laravel, query-string

I have a route like `browse/gpus?architecture[0]=Type1&architecture[1]=Type2` and I'm trying to make remove only one of the parameters when you click on an `a` tag so I'm using `fullUrlWithoutQuery('architecture')` however it completely removes both parameters instead of just one.

I've tried `fullUrlWithoutQuery('architecture[]')` and `fullUrlWithQuery(['architecture[]' => null]` but they both do the same thing. Any idea how I would go about removing just one out of the x possible parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`fullUrlWithoutQuery`](https://github.com/illuminate/http/blob/master/Request.php#L146) uses `Arr::except()` to remove keys mentioned in the parameters. Since, your `architecture` key is an array in itself, to remove value from any specific location, use the dot notation syntax like below:

```
<?php

dd(Arr::except(['architecture' => ['Type1', 'Type2']], ['architecture.0']));
```

[**Online Demo**](https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/972b6532-a799-45a7-b11c-f0c49fb874b3)

**For your case**, let' say you wish to remove the `0th` location, then it will be `->fullUrlWithoutQuery('architecture.0')`